# ExecuteMethodCall: The type 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]' must declare a default (parameterless) constructor

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I've sql Server 2000 DB which includes Stored Procedure that return Current DateTime.
And I've the procedure that call this procedure:

```
 [Function(Name = "dbo.spGetDBDateTime")]
public ISingleResult<DateTime?> GetDBDateTime()
{
    IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())),new object[]{} );
    return ((ISingleResult<DateTime?>)(result.ReturnValue));
}
```

I've got such error: The type 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]' must declare a default (parameterless) constructor in order to be constructed during mapping.

Could you help me, please?

Comment: Have you tried to make this non-nullable, if possible?

Comment: Post the stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need a custom stored procedure to get the current server datetime since the server already offers the T-SQL function GETDATE().  All you need to do is create a LINQ to SQL method pointing to that function.  Add the new method to your DataContext partial class (right-click on the designer surface and go View Code) like this:

```
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using System.Reflection;
using System;

namespace L2STest
{
    partial class MyDataContext
    {
        [Function(Name = "GetDate", IsComposable = true)]
        public DateTime GetSystemDate()
        {
            MethodInfo mi = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod() as MethodInfo;
            return (DateTime)this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, mi, new object[] { }).ReturnValue;
        }
    }
}
```

**And call it like this:**

```
DateTime serverDate = context.GetSystemDate();
```

Partial credit for this answer goes here :-)

http://peteohanlon.wordpress.com/2008/01/11/sql-server-getdate-and-linq-to-sql/

Comment: Right-click on WHAT designer surface? the data model (edmx)? I can't find any option for this anywhere. I've tried rolling my own but it doesn't recognise ExecuteMethodCall...

Comment: This answer (and question) was dealing with LINQ to SQL, not Entity Framework, which it sounds like you're using.  The surface I was referring to was the O/R designer surface you see when you add LINQ to SQL to your project in Visual Studio.  You might have found your answer already, but if not, there are several here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=entity+framework+server+getdate

Comment: Thx, I found System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.GetDate().

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry about my English )))
Hi, everyone!
Thank's for your helps, but I have just solved this problem self.**

In MS Visual Studio 2008 or later versions used Server Explorer => Data Connections =>Add new Connection and connected to my DB. Then in server Explorer was showed, as well as other items of DB, Stored Procedures and I just drew dbo.spGetDBDateTime procedure in code and VS generated wrap for this procedure, so I could called it.